# animate and scroll div to the top using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

Here I have created four div's red,blue,green and yellow and a nav menu linking to the respective div's. 
When I click the link on the nav I want the respective div to animate and scroll to the top.

I am new to jQuery so it's really difficult for me to figure out the solution.
Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the HTML, CSS and jquery.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="mainContent">
        <div id="redPage" class="red">
          <p>Red</p>
        </div>
        <div id="bluePage" class="blue">
          <p>blue</p>
        </div>
        <div id="greenPage" class="green">
          <p>green</p>
        </div>
        <div  id="yellowPage" class="yellow">
          <p>yellow</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <a href="#redPage">
          <li class="red">Red</li>
          </a> 

          <a href="#bluePage">
          <li class="blue">Blue</li>
          </a> 

          <a href="#greenPage">
          <li class="green">Green</li>
          </a>

          <a href="#yellowPage">
          <li class="yellow">Yellow</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
}
body {
overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper {
width: 960px;
height: 500px;
margin: 20px auto;
}
#mainContent {
float: right;
width: 800px;
height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#redPage {
width: 800px;
height: 500px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
#bluePage {
width: 800px;
height: 500px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
#greenPage {
width: 800px;
height: 500px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
#yellowPage {
width: 800px;
height: 500px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
nav {
float: left;
width: 160px;
}
nav li {
list-style-type: none;
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 30px;
color: white;
}
.red {
background: red;
}
.blue {
background: blue;
}
.green {
background: green;
}
.yellow {
background: yellow;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
 <script>
          $('document').ready(function() {
              $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
                  var $target=$(this.hash);
                  if($target.length==0) $target=$('a[name=" '+this.hash.substr(1)+' "]');
                  if($target.length==0) $target=$('#mainContent');

                  $("#mainContent").animate({scrollTop:$target.position().top},900);
                  return false;


              });

          }); 


 </script>
```

Comment: There's a typo in your jQuery block... "documennt"

Comment: Edited OP: JS-Fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/z4VuS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is nearly identical to anpsmn's, but I spent so long on it I'm posting it! I simplified your code a bit as well, so hopefully this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/LWUZz/1/

I also stored all positions in an `array`.

Answer (score 0):

The original code was calculating `$target.position().top` everytime you click the nav link. Hence your code works perfectly for the first time as `$target.position().top` returns correct top value but not the second time.

For this to work, you need to store the top values of all container on load itself.

Something like this

```
$('.content').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('data-top', $(this).position().top);
});
```

Here I have given a class `content` to all containers and on load I set an attribute `data-top` for all the containers and then use that `data-top` value to scroll.

```
$("#mainContent").animate({
    scrollTop: $target.attr('data-top')
}, 900);
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4VuS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div to only slide from bottom to top hiding the previous div, then check the following fiddle I created.

http://jsfiddle.net/F6gsy/

```
code
```

Note that I am new also to JQuery and please tell me if I am doing it the hard way and of any optimizations possible.